# Regex to filter out Datetime time from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

**Requirement:** I am receiving an email with a template and I need to filter out some text from the email. I am converting all the email body text as a string.

### email text looks like this:

```
some body text which I don't need 

Discussion:
Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-

TEST description - this should be logged as a comment.  --- This is the part I need

ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000
```

I was thinking of having a regex that looks for

- A word "Discussion"
- Next line look for DateTime format with "Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-"
- Pick up the next line until we find this line - "ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000" address

Is it possible? can someone plz help with regex?

TIA.

Comment: What regex language or tool are you using?

Comment: No tools. Plain javascript

Comment: javascript doesn't support \h in regex updated that with space in my answer

Comment: Please add a 'javascript' tag. It's always helpful to readers to show the desired results for examples given in SO questions. Can you do that?

Comment: I don't understand the point of having a regex in which `"Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-"` and `"ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000"` are hardwired. Is that the only date-time string and address that you are interested in matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was just about the content the OP is interested in, the following regex already is sufficient enough ... [`/Discussion:\n[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*\n+(?<content>.*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/3)

```js
const multilineMail = `Discussion:
Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-

TEST description - this should be logged as a comment.  --- This is the part I need

ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000`;


// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/3]
const regXMailContent =
  /Discussion:\n[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*\n+(?<content>.*)/;

console.log(
  regXMailContent.exec(multilineMail)?.groups?.content
);
```

In case the company footer has to match exactly, one has to make it part of the above regex like follows ... [`/Discussion:\n[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*\n+(?<content>.*)\n+ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000/`](https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/4)

```js
const multilineMail = `Discussion:
Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-

TEST description - this should be logged as a comment.  --- This is the part I need

ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000`;


// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/4]
const regXMailContent =
  /Discussion:\n[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*\n+(?<content>.*)\n+ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000/;

console.log(
  regXMailContent.exec(multilineMail)?.groups?.content
);
```

If the OP wants to also save date and user, one would enhance the firstly provided regex like with ...

- [`/Discussion:\n(?<date>[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}).*\n+(?<content>.*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/2)
- [`/Discussion:\n(?<date>[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\/[^/]+)\/\s*(?<user>.*?)-?\s*\n+(?<content>.*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/1)

```js
const multilineMail = `Discussion:
Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-

TEST description - this should be logged as a comment.  --- This is the part I need

ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000`;


// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/2]
const regXMailDateAndContent =
  /Discussion:\n(?<date>[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}).*\n+(?<content>.*)/;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/1]
const regXMailDateUserAndContent =
  /Discussion:\n(?<date>[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\/[^/]+)\/\s*(?<user>.*?)-?\s*\n+(?<content>.*)/;

console.log(
  regXMailDateAndContent.exec(multilineMail)?.groups
);
console.log(
  regXMailDateUserAndContent.exec(multilineMail)?.groups
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**But in case** the to be extracted content is a multiline text, the **regex has to feature the company footer** in order to identify the correct match. The 2ndly provided regex then changes to ... [`/Discussion:\n[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*\n+(?<content>(?:.*\n)*)ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000/`](https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/5)

```js
const multilineMail = `Discussion:
Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-

TEST

description - this should be
logged as a comment.  --- This is

the part I need


ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000`;


// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/v8FXCA/5]
const regXMailMultilineContent =
  /Discussion:\n[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s+\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}.*\n+(?<content>(?:.*\n)*)ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000/;

console.log(
  regXMailMultilineContent.exec(multilineMail)?.groups?.content
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

All of the above regex patterns make use of [`named capturing groups`](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex:

```
Discussion.*?\n+([A-Za-z]+ +(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}\/\d+:\d+ +[^\n]+)(.*)?ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000
```

Explanation:

1. `Discussion.*?\n+` The regex starts from where the String `Discussion` begins.
2. `.*?\n+` keeps looking for additional word and newlines
3. `([A-Za-z]+ +(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}\/\d+:\d+ +[^\n]+)` next it looks for the date format as you described . It will fetch all until it reaches a newline `[^\n+]`
4. `(.*)?`It will fetch everything from the previous date line
5. `ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000` and will
   conclude matching whenever it finds this.
6. Here I have kept the Date format line in group 1 and the body you
   need in group 2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JlMLDJ/1)

source:

```js
const regex = /Discussion.*?\n+([A-Za-z]+ +(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}\/\d+:\d+ +[^\n]+)(.*)?ABC Company Australia \| XYZ St \| Sydney NSW 2000/gms;

const str = `some body text which I don't need 

Discussion:
Tue 26/04/2022/2:48 PM UTC+10/ ABC User-

TEST description - this should be logged as a comment.  --- This is the part I need

ABC Company Australia | XYZ St | Sydney NSW 2000
`;

var match = regex.exec(str);
if(match!=null){
console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
}
```